# Error while getting gridview cell value: Input string was not in a correct format

Tags: c#, gridview

i have this code 
that when i click on this button on the `gridview`, it delete the row that i click the delete button behind it:

```
 private void imgbtnDelete_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)     
 {
        //Get the button that raised the event
        ImageButton btn = (ImageButton)sender;

        //Get the row that contains this button
        GridViewRow gvr = (GridViewRow)btn.NamingContainer;

        //Get rowindex
        int rowindex = gvr.RowIndex;
        int DrillItemId = Convert.ToInt32(grd1.Rows[rowindex].Cells[0].Text.ToString());
        SPContext.Current.Web.Lists["Drill Items"].Items.DeleteItemById(DrillItemId);

        grd1.DataSource = GetData();
        grd1.DataBind();
    }
```

when i deploy my project it give me this error in this line:
the line that have the error:

```
int DrillItemId = Convert.ToInt32(grd1.Rows[rowindex].Cells[0].Text.ToString());
```

the error:

`input string was not in a correct format.`

please help me

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10647/how-do-i-write-a-good-title

Comment: Have you ever considered to acutally make a subject line that has any logical sense except demonstrating you are capable of whining?

Comment: What is the value of `grd1.Rows[rowindex].Cells[0].Text` exactly?

Comment: Please choose a more meaningful title. Your current title could invariably be used for *every single* question on StackOverflow.

Comment: It's very obvious. The value of the first column in your grid is not an integer.

Comment: Add a break point and see what is the exact value of `grd1.Rows[rowindex].Cells[0].Text`

Comment: the value of grd1.Rows[rowindex].cells[0].text :

Answer (score 2):

> please help me

Well, the error is:

> input string was not in a correct format.

and the line is:

> int DrillItemId = Convert.ToInt32(grd1.Rows[rowindex].Cells[0].Text.ToString());

Let's see. I would guess that whatever you have in the `Cells[0].Text` is not a number. Or at least not in a form that `Convert.ToInt32` will accept. I will not go into possible reasons here - there are many, depending how you use it.

Can you just do baseline debugging and check that and - ah  - fix that? It is only slightly more complex than writing a title that does not say "Hello i need a help please" and something programmers normally learn very early in their career... debugging.

Answer (score 1):

In following line

`int DrillItemId = Convert.ToInt32(grd1.Rows[rowindex].Cells[0].Text.ToString());`

The actual value of `grd1.Rows[rowindex].Cells[0].Text` might be containing alphabetic characters or the whitespace so you are getting this error.

`Convert.ToInt32(stringVal)` actually converts the specified string representation of a number to an equivalent 32-bit signed integer but the parameter should be a string that contains the number only.